# Sending bytes commands to a Star Micronics SM-S220I printer

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, hex, byte

I'm trying to get my head around how this works. I want to change the font size of a specific word in the ticket.

On the manual, it says that the character size is changed with the following commands:

```
ASCI: GS ! n
HEX: 1D 21 n
```

Where n represents both height and width expansions. Bit 0 to 2 sets the character width. Bit 4 to 6 sets the character height.

So I tried these different code variations:

```
[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x00"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x00") - 1];   
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD1\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x02"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x02") - 1]; 
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD2\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x04"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x04") - 1]; 
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD3\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x06"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x06") - 1]; 
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD4\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x08"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x08") - 1];
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD5\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x10"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x10") - 1];
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD6\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x12"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x12") - 1]; 
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD7\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x14"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x14") - 1]; 
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD8\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x16"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x16") - 1]; 
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD9\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x18"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x18") - 1]; 
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD10\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x19"
               length:sizeof("\x1d\x21\x19") - 1]; 
[commands appendData:[@"ABCD11\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

Which give me this result:

[image]

Which is totally unexpected, at least for me. Can anyone help me understand how this works? 
The final output I would like is to get the height of ABCD9 but with a proportional width.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know that printer, but from your example output it seems that bits 0-2 define
the height, and bits 4-6 the width of the character (just the other way around from what
you described). So the bits of `n` are

```
0www0hhh
```

The string "ABCD9" is printed with `n = \x16 = 00010110`, which corresponds
to height = 6 (binary `110`) and width = 1 (binary `001`).
To get the string printed with width = height = 6 you would need

```
n = 01100110 = 0x66
```

therefore

```
[commands appendBytes:"\x1d\x21\x66" length:3];
```

Comment: I'll try it out and come back to you. In the meantime, could you tell me where I can find information so I can understand why `\x16 = 00010110` and `6 = binary 110` ? Thanks!

Comment: @Jan: `\x` stands a for hexadecimal number. Perhaps have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal for a start.